# Simple OR circuit with 2 inputs

Tags: diodes

I would like an or circuit with two inputs and one output. It will be operating at 12v dc with less 1 amp current. Either input would be capable of providing this power. However the inputs cannot (obviously) be in any way connected.

I was wondering of the simplest way of implementing this? Would a diode or circuit work? Excuse my ignorance, any help much appreciated.

Comment: The two outputs may not be electrically connected? No common ground?

Comment: they do have a common ground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi4MMx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Diode circuit. (b) Relay circuit.*

> Would a diode or circuit work?

A diode circuit would work but would result in a 0.7 V drop in voltage.

The alternative is to use a relay to prioritise one supply over the other. Figure 1b shows that V4 will energise the relay and supply the output. When V4 is off V3 will supply the output. The relay contact will not drop any voltage but the relay coil will consume some current.

Comment: What would happen if V1 and V2 are both low? The voltage at Vout would be undefined. I would certainly use a pull down resistor at the Vout node.

Comment: Given the simplicity of the question I have assumed that this a power-supply problem rather than a logic / micro-controller question and that pull-down is not required.

Comment: the relay circuit would solve my problem. If both are low then the relay goes into its 'rest' position, defaulting to V3...?

Comment: +1 But I'd add... Don't use the relay circuit if you are hot swapping your power if you need the power to be continuous. There will be a break in power as the relay switches.

Comment: I never thought of that; you are right. The output is only powering a light though so a small flicker when switching wont matter in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use two diodes connected like an OR gate but if you want 12 volts out with 12 volts in you will be disappointed that you might only get 11.3 volts out due to the volt drops in the diodes. You might get 0.5 volts lost in a schottky diode.

Or you can use a power path controller

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand ur question are trying to use 2 different signals to operate a relay when one or both could be signaling the relay? If that's the case Just use a solid state relay an wire both signals to it they can take up to 32v input signal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).